# Re-load data to an editable grid using data in hidden textarea

Tags: javascript, grid

I'm trying to create an editable table primarily with options. Using this: http://codepen.io/ashblue/pen/mCtuA

My only challenge right now is that instead of the text fields, I am trying to replace them with select options that are populated dynamically. For instance; my two select options are:

```
  <select id="Country"></select>
  <select id="City"></select>
```

The other challenge I have is that, once the options are filled, I want to be able to refresh the page and have the same line items options load again.

The editable grid has a JSON, output, so far I have created a hidden textarea in the page and then when I reload, I am trying to re-populate the values where the User last entered.

Does anyone have any ideas or a better way to do this?